# Python sklearn one-hot encoding for missing categories

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset I want to do one-hot encoding on (from sklearn). One column is age. Ideally, I would want it to be 0-100. But I only have scattered age data in the dataset, so when I run sklearn one-hot encoder, it only categorizes the existing age samples.

The column looks like:

```
Age
55 
8 
26
40 
45
...     
25
36
28
50
35
```

The sklearn piece of code I have and the result:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
enc.fit_transform(X_train)
enc.categories_

(print)
...(other encoded columns)
Age column:
array([ 0,  7,  8,  9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
        42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 56, 57, 58, 60,
        61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 70, 75])
```

Is there a way to get it encoded as:

```
array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...,70,71,72,73,74,75]) hopefully even more (to 100)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure that it is faster/better to have a categorical with 100 entries than performing a regression?

Answer (score 0):

you can use categorical variables before casting with pd.get_dummies:

```
import pandas as pd
age = pd.Series([ 0,  7,  8,  9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 56, 57, 58, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 70, 75])

age = age.astype(pd.Categorical(range(0,101)))
df = pd.get_dummies(age)
```

output:

```
df.columns

# CategoricalIndex([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
                  ...
                   91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100],
                 categories=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...], ordered=False, dtype='category', length=101)
```

Comment: age = age.astype(pd.Categorical(range(0,101))) does not run. Gives me an error:  Cannot interpret '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
Length: 101
Categories (101, int64): [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 97, 98, 99, 100]' as a data type